# How use mongoose distinct, skip and limit together

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to use `skip` and `limit` for pagination, and the `distinct` for not return equal values.

If i use

```
MyModel.find().distinct('blaster', function(err, results) {
    res.render('index', {
        data: results
    });
});
```

This works.

If i use

```
MyModel.find().sort('brand').skip((page-1)*15).limit(15).exec(function(err, results) {
    res.render('index', {
        data: results
    });
});
```

This is also working, but how use both?

If i try, the error will show:

```
Error: skip cannot be used with distinct
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't do that. [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) is a method that returns an "array", and therefore you cannot modify something that is not a "Cursor" with "cursor modifiers" like `.limit()` and `.skip()`.

What you want is the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. Much more than just adding things up:

```js
MyModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": { "_id": "$blaster" } },
        { "$skip": ( page-1 ) * 15 },
        { "$limit": 15 }
    ],
    function(err,results) {
       // results skipped and limited in here
    }
);
```

The  aggregation framework provides another way to achieve "distinct" results. But in a more flexible way. See the operators for [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), [**`$skip`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/).

Comment: this is working in parts, is returning what i want, but it is an object, I need to send for my views in a way that I can print in the html without appear '[object Object]'

Comment: @SuchMuchFunny It works. An array of objects that will JSON Stringify perfectly, just like any other result from the mongoose API. You are doing something wrong if you cannot make it work. It's pretty simple for the rest of us.

Comment: @SuchMuchFunny Nothing in MongoDB will do that. Your code needs to tranform the results or your "views" need to respect "key/value" principles. SQL Databases don't do that. Why would you expect something else of a different datastore?