# Use distinct, or, skip, limit, AND sort in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find distinct conversations sorted by timestamp and with conditions that `sender` is `userId` or `recipient` is `userId`. I think the only way to do this is with aggregations. This is what I have right now:

```
Notification.aggregate([
        // { $or: [ { $sender: userId }, { $recipient: userId } ] },
        { $group: { _id: '$conversationId' } },
        { $skip: (page - 1) * LIMIT },
        { $limit: LIMIT },
        { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } }
    ], function (err, result) {
        // console.log(result);
        return result;
    });
```

However, I am getting a "double callback" error with this (hence why I commented out the offending `$or` line.

The pseudocode (that I am trying to achieve) is:

```
Notification.find().or([
    { sender: userId },
    { recipient: userId }
])
.distinct('conversationId')
.sort('-timestamp')
.limit(LIMIT)
.skip((page - 1) * LIMIT)
.exec(function (error, result) {
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Some of these things (if not all) can be achieved through knowing how to use mongoose's [`find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

Then, you should order these commands. The correct order is:

- `sort` and `limit` are **options** commands
- `$or` is a **conditions** command, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382207/mongooses-find-method-with-or-condition-does-not-work-properly)
- Finally, you must leave `distinct` as a separated statement, since it returns [an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27947464/3505157), and is not chainable.

You'll end up having this –theoretical– piece of code

```
Notification.find({
    $or: [
        sender: userId,
        recipient: userId
    ]
}, undefined, {
    skip: (page - 1) * LIMIT,
    limit: LIMIT,
    sort: {
        timestamp: 1
    }
}).distinct('conversationId', (err, results) => {
    // ***
});
```

I encourage you to test it, however I'm not assuring any results. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: This does not work. Limit cannot be used with distinct.

Comment: Actually, any of the `options` statements can't be used along with distinct. We'd have to find out what's going on with the "double callback" thing.
By the way: why are you using a return inside a callback?

Comment: @roscioli, can you give me a test set of data, so I can figure out a solution?